# IOS AVplayer when app is in background

Tags: ios, background, location, avplayer

Greetings

I would like to play an audio whenever a location manager delegate is called.This works when the app is in foreground. But it doesn’t’ play when the app is in background. The delegate is called.
I am printing the app state which logs 2(background)

I am using iPhone 6 OS 8.2 Xcode 6.3.2

info.plist  CustomIOS target properties

Required background modes
item 0 - App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay

Please let me know what could be the problem

```
test.h
```

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusicPlayer;

test.m

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    UIApplicationState state = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
    NSLog(@"app state %ld",state);

    NSLog(@"Playing sound");

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    // Create audio player with background music
    NSString *backgroundMusicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“mysong” ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicPath];

    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:nil];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.delegate = self;  // We need this so we can restart after interruptions
    //   self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // Negative number means loop forever

    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];

}
```